# An analog of weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits in PyTorch

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to train a model with PyTorch. Is there any simple way to create a loss like [`weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits) from Tensorflow?

There are `pos_weight` argument in `weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits` that can help with balancing. But there are only weights for labels in the list of arguments in [`BCEWithLogitsLoss`](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss).

Comment: BTW I've implemented `pos_weight` and the corresponding pull request was merged into PyTorch 0.4.1. See [the docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own custom loss function as you want. For example, you can write:

```
def weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, target, pos_weight):
    return targets * -logits.sigmoid().log() * pos_weight + 
               (1 - targets) * -(1 - logits.sigmoid()).log()
```

This is a basic implementation. You should follow the steps mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits) to ensure stability and avoid overflow. Just use the final formulation that they derived.

Comment: But for single data-point, I want loss to be a scalar. For Example `True Label: [0,0,0,1,0,1]` and `predicted output` is `logits: [0.01, -2.67, -1.03, -3.67, 0.87,-1.11]` for this weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits should return single value of loss?